# Bootstrap Social Buttons Background Color and Hovering Issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap to create the social buttons for Facebook and LinkedIn. When I set the background color to white for the buttons, it doesn't properly cover the button. The white background starts to cover outside the social buttons. It looks like this:[image]

I set it to white because if I don't then the letters become the same color as the grey background.

This is the code that I have set up in CSS:

```
.social a {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background-color: white;
  color: #3b5998;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background-color: white;
  color: #0e76a8;
}

.fa-facebook:hover, .fa-linkedin:hover {
  color: #d5d5d5;
}
```

And this is the code I have in HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" class="row text-center padding">
        <div style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"  class="col-12 social">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/westernUBT/"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/western-hasp/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also when I hover over the buttons, it seems to detect the click from outside the social media icon area. Like if I hover around the grey area close to social media icons, it seems to detect it and I don't know why.

Comment: its hovering over the padding

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using pseudo-element `:after`.
First, remove the white background from the icons. Then, add `position: relative` to the icons, because the pseudo-element will be absolutely positioned.

The icon must be in front of this new pseudo-element. That is, the `:before` will have higher `z-index`.

So, you position it in center just enough to cause the white effect you need.
It may not work with all different icons.

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #333
}
.social a {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.fa-facebook {
  color: #3b5998;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  color: #0e76a8;
}

.fa-facebook:hover, .fa-linkedin:hover {
  color: #d5d5d5;
}

.social i {
  position: relative;
}

.social i:before {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.social i:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 88%;
  width: 88%;
  left: 6%;
  top: 6%;
}
```

For the click area issue, you can replace padding with margin and use font-size to the icon itself (`<i>`) instead of `<a>`.